# Wrong position of vertical lines in plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, seaborn

In my project I have class that generate PDF report using data that were wrote in GUI. Part of report is plot. I using next code:

```
self.flat_data = [self.table_N[i][j] for i in range(5) for j in range(1,6)]
        
sns.displot(self.flat_data, kind="kde", bw_adjust=1.0)
plt.axvline(self.LotM_N, color='g', label='Значення лоту')
plt.axvline(self.gm_N, color='r', label='Середнє')
plt.axvline(self.vib_N, color='gold', label='Межі зміщення')
plt.axvline(self.vitop_N, color='gold', label='Межі зміщення')
plt.title("Оцінка розподілу")
plt.xlabel("Розподіл")
plt.ylabel("Значення")
    
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('foo.png', dpi=600)
    
im2 = Image('foo.png', width=56*mm, height=56*mm)
table13 = Table([[im2]], colWidths=115*mm, rowHeights=56*mm)
```

Where, `self.table_N` is 2d array, that is passed to class from GUI:

```
self.table_N=[['1', 3.71, 3.77, 3.64, 3.7, 3.79], 
        ['2', 3.76, 3.55, 3.67, 3.73, 3.76],
        ['3', 3.64, 3.79, 3.81, 3.82, 3.82], 
        ['4', 3.73, 3.66, 3.7, 3.81, 3.7], 
        ['5', 3.79, 3.57, 3.69, 3.7, 3.75]]
```

And `self.LotM_N, self.gm_N, self.vib_N, self.vitop_N` are float, positive variables. They also passed from GUI, this is how they looked like (using print): 3.9 3.72 3.68 4.12.
This code create plot, but vertical lines are in wrong places, https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqwA6.png

But whene I recreate this plot separately from PDF report, it works fine:

```
LotM_N=3.9
gm_N=3.7
vib_N=3.68
vitop_N=4.12
table_N=[['1', 3.71, 3.77, 3.64, 3.7, 3.79], 
        ['2', 3.76, 3.55, 3.67, 3.73, 3.76],
        ['3', 3.64, 3.79, 3.81, 3.82, 3.82], 
        ['4', 3.73, 3.66, 3.7, 3.81, 3.7], 
        ['5', 3.79, 3.57, 3.69, 3.7, 3.75]]
flat_data1=[table_N[i][j] for i in range(5) for j in range(1,6)]

sns.displot(flat_data1,  kind="kde", bw_adjust=1.0)
plt.axvline(LotM_N, color='g', label='Значення лоту')
plt.axvline(gm_N, color='r', label='Середнє')
plt.axvline(vib_N, color='gold', label='Межі зміщення')
plt.axvline(vitop_N, color='gold', label='Межі зміщення')
plt.title("Оцінка розподілу")
plt.xlabel("Розподіл")
plt.ylabel("Значення")

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('foo.png', dpi=600)

plt.show()
```

got this, and this is how it should be https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftSak.png
What Im doing wrong?

Comment: The plot looks like the vertical lines have strings for the x-axis instead of numbers. So, `self.gm_N` etc seem to be strings, while `self.LotM_N` seems to be numeric.